# Trouble finding most recent sync on 10,000 devices in database with over 100 million rows

Tags: mysql

My database has 147 million rows representing POS device transactions.  I need to find the most recent transaction for 10,000 devices.  I'm using a server with 20 processors and 240GB RAM and RAID 0 SSD.  MySQL is configured to use all server resources.

This is the SQL query:

```
select v1.device_id as device_id, v1.module_id as module_id, v1.db_sync_done as
db_sync_done, v1.machine_id as machine_id
from report2 v1 where v1.db_sync_done = 
(select max(v2.db_sync_done) from report2 v2 where v1.device_id = v2.device_id);
```

Query runs forever.  Yes, fields are indexed.  Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Some comments.

Your original query will generate 'correlated sub-query' for inner `SELECT MAX ...` which means inner query will be evaluated for each row in `v1` table, indeed really poor performance.

```
SELECT v1.device_id as device_id, v1.module_id as module_id,
  v1.db_sync_done as db_sync_done, v1.machine_id as machine_id
FROM report2 v1
WHERE v1.db_sync_done = 
(SELECT MAX(v2.db_sync_done) FROM report2 v2 WHERE v1.device_id = v2.device_id);
```

But when you run your query in self-answer, `asum` is evaluated once so it is fater than original query.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM vs_metrics_report a INNER JOIN
(SELECT device_id, MAX(metric_id) as metric_id
 FROM vs_metrics_report
 GROUP BY device_id
) asum ON asum.device_id = a.device_id AND a.metric_id = asum.metric_id
ORDER BY a.metric_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this and got faster results but all rows are returning so it's useless.  I need distinct devices.  :(

```
select a.*
from vs_metrics_report a join
(select device_id, max(metric_id) as metric_id
 from vs_metrics_report
 group by device_id
) asum
on asum.device_id = a.device_id and a.metric_id = asum.metric_id
order by a.metric_id DESC;
```